# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' with Jacoco

Tags: java, testng, liquibase, jacoco

I get a following error when try to run tests (Test NG) + jacoco + liquibase

```html
15:49:50 ERROR ConfigurableSpringLiquibaseExecutor:afterPropertiesSet:77 error for changelog=classpath:liquibase/test.db.changelog-master.xml, url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useColumnNamesInFindColumn=true&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=false&useSSL=false, user=tsv@localhost
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The liquibase instance was initialized earlier.
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:89)
```

I'm using following libraries and plugins:

- liquibase-core: 2.0.5
- liquibase-maven-plugin: 2.0.5
- jacoco-maven-plugin: 0.7.5.201505241946
- maven-surefire-plugin: 2.15
- java: 1.8

When I turn liquibase off then test is running and report generates successfully

Comment: Can you run only one test to check if the error is still happening ? Check if you do not instanciate liquibase twice or more.

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Yes I can There is no any errors if I'm running test with out Jacoco. Should I share my maven-surefire-plugin configuration ?

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Yes I can There is no any errors if I'm running test with out Jacoco. Should I share my maven-surefire-plugin configuration ?